# RUBY: Combining 2 different arrays with duplicate values into hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have 2 Arrays.

```
product_name = ["Pomegranate", "Raspberry", "Miracle fruit", "Raspberry"]
product_quantity =  [2, 4, 5, 5]
```

I'd like to know how to initialize a hash such that it becomes

```
product_hash = {"Pomegranate"=>2, "Raspberry"=>9, "Miracle fruit"=>5}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with something like this:

```
product_name.zip(product_quantity)
            .group_by(&:first)
            .map { |k, v| [k, v.map(&:last).inject(:+)] }
            .to_h
#=> { "Pomegranate" => 2, "Raspberry" => 9, "Miracle fruit" => 5}
```

I suggest to lookup each method in the Ruby's docs for [`Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html) and [`Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html) and to check in the console what each the  intermediate step returns.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`each_with_object`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_object):

```
product_name.zip(product_quantity)
            .each_with_object({}) {|(k, v), h| h[k] ? h[k] += v : h[k] = v }
#=> {"Pomegranate"=>2, "Raspberry"=>9, "Miracle fruit"=>5}
```

Or just use hash with default value:

```
product_name.zip(product_quantity)
            .each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|(k, v), h| h[k] += v }
#=> {"Pomegranate"=>2, "Raspberry"=>9, "Miracle fruit"=>5}
```

Comment: No need for default proc when the defaut is immutable.

Comment: I meant to say that you can just write `Hash.new(0)`

Comment: @Eric, yes, sure. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

This is but a slight variation of @llya's solution #2.

```
product_name.each_index.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |i,h|
  h[product_name[i]] += h[product_quantity[i]] }            .
```

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't we just do:

```
product_name.zip(product_quantity).to_h
```

Seems to return the correct result for me?

Comment: It doesn't sum the "Raspberry", whose total quantity is 9. Your solution returns 5.

Comment: My bad :( DId not see that there were duplicated entries

Comment: Consider deleting your answer to avoid more downvotes.